# How can I selectively colour histogram bars in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I did 10,000 stochastic implementations of a model, and want to plot some outputs. Long story short, the plot shows how long two species co-occurred within the system on a given run. Here's an example:
[image]

Now, I want to colour the histogram bars to specify which species lasted longer within the system. Specifically, I want to be able to specify if Species A outlasted Species B, if Species B outlasted Species A, or if both species went "extinct" at the same time, within a given simulation.

So, I made three vectors containing the run numbers (out of 10,000) for each of these three outcomes. For example:

```
# Pi wins
PiWins_1 <- which(Winner_1[1:10000, 2] %in% TRUE)
head(PiWins_1)
# [1]  1  2  6  7  9 12

# Pj wins
PjWins_1 <- which(Winner_1[1:10000, 3] %in% TRUE)
head(PjWins_1)
# [1]  3  4  5  8 10 11

# Ties
Ties_1 <- which(Winner_1[1:10000, 4] %in% TRUE)
head(Ties_1)
# [1]  20  24  29  40 110 132
```

And am now trying to figure out how to use these (or some other method) to colour each of the 10,000 histogram bars accordingly?

This is the ggplot script so far:

```
Histogram_1 <- ggplot(temp_df_1, aes(x=persistance_vec_1))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = "darkseagreen2")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean_pv_1, colour = "Mean # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs"))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = cmean_pv_1, colour = "Conditional Mean # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs (Dashed)"), linetype=2)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median_pv_1, colour = "Median # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs"))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = cmedian_pv_1, colour = "Conditional Median # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs (Dashed)"), linetype=2)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = DO_1, colour = "Overlap in Det Sim"))+
  labs(title="Det vs Stoch Overlap; Intro @ 1, 10000 sims",
       x="# of Time Pts Pi and Pj Co-occur",
       y="# of Sims")+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",
                      values=c("Mean # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs" = "navyblue",
                               "Conditional Mean # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs (Dashed)" = "navyblue",
                               "Median # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs" = "red2",
                               "Conditional Median # of Overlapping Time Pts in Stoch Runs (Dashed)" = "red2",
                               "Overlap in Det Sim" = "orange"))+
  theme_minimal()
Histogram_1
```

Please let me know if I should provide any more information! Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: Don't know what to do with your data, but `ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill=factor(cyl)))` changes the color based on `cyl`, hope this helps.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/pretty-histograms-with-ggplot2) that uses the `cut()` function. Let me know if helps, because I have the same problem.

Comment: BTW, I don't know what to do with your data because we don't have it. If you want help specific to your data, please [edit] your question and provide a minimal working example including sample data (preferably provided with `dput(.)`). Realize that we don't have to have *all* of the data, in fact we don't need real data at all if you can make something representative using random data. It doesn't have to look like an awesome gaussian histogram to show you how to color properly.

Comment: Hey all! Thanks so much for the info––in the future, I'll definitely post a replicable example! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I think what you're asking for is just how to colour bars by different colours. Here's a reprex:

```
x =  c(1:10)
y = c(11:15, 15:11)
z = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 10, replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
```

And then the plot - you can just use the `fill` argument in `geom_col()` if you want to use ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
df$z = as.factor(df$z)
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z), colour = "black")
```

[image]

Does this do what you're looking to do?

Or if you really want to use `geom_histogram()`, here's an option with a different reprex:

```
# make the numeric data
x = sample(c(1:10), 50, replace = TRUE)
# initialize empty vector for categorical variables
z = vector(mode = "character", length = 50)
# im making 3 groups that i've randomly decided to group
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  z[i] = ifelse(x[i] %in% c(1,3,5,7,9), # if x is an odd number, z=A
         "A",
         ifelse(x[i] %in% c(2,4,6), # if x in (2,4,6), z=B, if not, z=C
                "B", "C"))
}
#turn into dataframe
df = data.frame(x = x, z = z)
```

and then the plot using the same idea:

```
df$z = as.factor(df$z)
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = x, fill = z), colour = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, @colebrookson! This worked! In the future, I will ask questions with this format :)